# MAMP PRO Windows Beta Expired

Tags: windows, mamp, beta

I have installed latest Beta 1 of MAMP Pro for Windows, but it has expired and there is no new beta image available. 
What can I do ?

Comment: I have the same issue now..

Comment: New beta has been released, all is working fine now.